# How to set a flag as default on an *.EXE file?

Tags: windows, command-line-arguments, flag

When I open Sumatra I need inverted colors by default. But even though I changed the shortcuts to: `"/sumatraPDF.exe" -invert-colors` the program runs without the flag when I double click a `PDF` file at a time where the program is closed.

How do I make sure the flag is used when double clicking `PDF` files?

Comment: Your program shortcuts are unrelated to the extension association.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

#### How do I make sure the flag is used when double clicking pdf files?

You need to modify the command that is run, using [ftype](http://ss64.com/nt/ftype.html):

1. Find out the file type using [assoc](http://ss64.com/nt/assoc.html):

   ```
   assoc .pdf
   ```
2. This will return something similar to:

   ```
   .pdf=AcroExch.Document.DC
   ```
3. Now use [ftype](http://ss64.com/nt/ftype.html) to get the current command run for a .pdf:

   ```
   ftype AcroExch.Document.DC
   ```
4. This will return something similar to:

   ```
   AcroExch.Document.DC="C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" "%1"
   ```
5. Now set up a new command with your extra flag:

   ```
   ftype AcroExch.Document.DC="C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" -invert-colors "%1"
   ```

Note:

- I've used Acrobat in my example above as I don't have Sumatra installed.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [assoc](http://ss64.com/nt/assoc.html) - Display or change the association between a file extension and a fileType
- [ftype](http://ss64.com/nt/ftype.html) - Display or change the link between a FileType and an executable program.

Comment: @Coolwater Great!

Comment: You can do the same thing by editing the registry directly, but instead of using `ftype`, you'll be chasing references starting at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pdf`.

Comment: @Mark I know. I went for the simpler, less dangerous approach :)

Comment: Oh, nice. And it should work form WinXP forward.

Comment: I think it might be worth mentioning that application updates and upgrades might overwrite these changes so it might be something that has to be done repeatedly. I would expect this from Adobe at least.